# Bouncy Castle Encrypt in Java Decrypt in .Net

Tags: java, c#, encryption, bouncycastle

I used the following to encrypt a string using a password

```
    static String algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC";
static byte[] salt = "b9v4n38s".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
static int derivedKeyLength = 128;
static int iterations = 20000;

public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, String password) throws NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, derivedKeyLength);
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    SecretKey key = f.generateSecret(spec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);   
    byte[] text = plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);         
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text);
    return encrypted;
}
```

The result of this is base64 encoded and sent as arg[0] to .Net (arg[1] is the same password). Now I'm trying to decrypt that string in .Net with this code

```
    private static string Decrypt(string[] args)
    {
        int derivedKeyLength = 128;
        int iterations = 20000;
        string algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC";
        byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("b9v4n38s");

        PbeParametersGenerator pGen = new Pkcs12ParametersGenerator(new Sha256Digest());
        pGen.Init(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args[1]), salt, iterations);
        ICipherParameters par = pGen.GenerateDerivedParameters("AES256", derivedKeyLength);
        IBufferedCipher c = CipherUtilities.GetCipher(algorithm);
        c.Init(false, par);
        var input = Convert.FromBase64String(args[0]);
        byte[] enc = c.DoFinal(input);
        var decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(enc);
        return decoded;
    }
```

Unfortunately it fails on DoFinal with message `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: 'pad block corrupted'`

`SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm)` uses the same algorithm string as `Cipher.getInstance(algorithm)` in java but if I try `pGen.GenerateDerivedParameters(algorithm, derivedKeyLength);` in .Net it throws `Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecurityUtilityException: 'Algorithm PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC not recognised.'`

I'm not set on this algorithm, just looking for a way to encrypt a string in Java and decrypt it in .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible C#/BC code to decrypt a ciphertext generated with the posted Java code is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
...
private static string algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC";
private static byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("b9v4n38s");
private static int iterations = 20000;

public static string Decrypt(string ciphertextB64, string password)
{
    IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher(algorithm);
    Asn1Encodable algParams = PbeUtilities.GenerateAlgorithmParameters(algorithm, salt, iterations);
    ICipherParameters cipherParams = PbeUtilities.GenerateCipherParameters(algorithm, password.ToCharArray(), algParams);
    cipher.Init(false, cipherParams);

    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertextB64);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.DoFinal(cipherBytes);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
}
```

Test:

```cs
string decrypted = Decrypt("mBy4YwAvUpvoSJhzBnpOCJw2kCayvdYfLJ/12x0BgUKh5m5bvArSheMMs2U5rYyE", "MyPassword");
Console.WriteLine(decrypted); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

where the ciphertext was generated with the Java code using the password *MyPassword*.

Please note that a static salt is generally insecure (except for testing purposes of course).